# useEffect hooks A unmount fired after B mount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am using a custom `IsEditedContext`. There are 3 status, `initial`, `edited`, and `unedited`. `shouldRefresh` is depending on `status`. I am using `react-router-dom` to navigate across the page with `<Link>` component.

The expected result of the context is:

1. I navigate to `First` page, `status` is initial, `shouldRefresh` is true.
2. API in `First` page is called, `markAsUnedited` is called.
3. I navigate to `Second` page, trigger the useEffect callback for `First` page, which change the `status` to initial and `shouldRefresh` to true.
4. API in `Second` page is called, `markAsUnedited` is called.

**IsEditedContext**

```
import { FC, PropsWithChildren, createContext, useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';

enum EditStatus {
  Initial = 'initial',
  Edited = 'edited',
  Unedited = 'unedited',
}

interface IsEditedContextType {
  shouldRefresh: boolean;
  status: EditStatus;
  markAsEdited: () => void;
  markAsUnedited: () => void;
  init: () => void;
}

const defaultContext: IsEditedContextType = {
  status: EditStatus.Initial,
  markAsEdited: () => {},
  markAsUnedited: () => {},
  shouldRefresh: false,
  init: () => {},
};

const IsEditedContext = createContext<IsEditedContextType>(defaultContext);

export const useIsEdited = (resetOnUnmount = false) => {
  const context = useContext(IsEditedContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useIsEdited must be used within a IsEditedProvider');
  }
  if (resetOnUnmount) {
    useEffect(() => {
      return context.init;
    }, []);
  }
  return context;
};

export const IsEditedProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<EditStatus>(EditStatus.Initial);

  const markAsEdited = useCallback(() => setStatus(EditStatus.Edited), []);
  const markAsUnedited = useCallback(() => setStatus(EditStatus.Unedited), []);
  const init = useCallback(() => setStatus(EditStatus.Initial), []);

  const shouldRefresh = useMemo(() => {
    return status === EditStatus.Initial || status === EditStatus.Edited;
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <IsEditedContext.Provider value={{ status, init, markAsEdited, markAsUnedited, shouldRefresh }}>
      {children}
    </IsEditedContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**First and Second page**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useIsEdited } from "../IsEditedContext";

const First = () => {
  const { shouldRefresh, markAsUnedited } = useIsEdited(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldRefresh) {
      console.log('First page API call');
      markAsUnedited();
    };
  }, []);
  return ( <>First</> );
}

export default First;
```

**Problem encounter**

The unmount for `First` is fired after the mount of `Second`, which does not clean up the status to initial and cause the API is `Second` is not called.

[Demo reproduce of the problem](https://playcode.io/1608954)

Answer (score 0):

inside your effect, in the if condition, try `return () => init`. when the component unmounts, after it refreshed, it will reset your memo, which will clear the if condition, and clean up on unmount

Comment: Sorry, which useEffect do you refers to, the page or the context?

Comment: inside your `First` and `Second`

Comment: Just tested it out and it is not working as expected, I have tried `return () => init()` as well

Comment: right. just looked at your code. you need to add the hook values you use as your dependencies. so you need to have `shouldRefetch` and `markAsUnread` in the dependency array. otherwise you are operating on stale closures

Comment: Passing shouldRefresh will cause an infinity loop in useEffect

Comment: Now you have to look at how you’re setting state and if you need that pattern at all. If you don’t add those dependencies, your effect will run once and have inconsistent results

Comment: Thanks for helping, I think I have found the solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

After few trials with different approach, I found the solution, but still figuring why it is working...

```
export const useIsEdited = (resetOnUnmount = false) => {
  const context = useContext(IsEditedContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useIsEdited must be used within a IsEditedProvider');
  }
  if (resetOnUnmount) {
    useEffect(() => {
      return context.init;
    }, [context]); // <-- Add the Context here
  }
  return context;
};
```

I need to add the context into the useEffect dependencies. Appreciate if any can help to explain this...